# How to reset CKAN's admin password using database

Tags: ckan

How to reset CKAN's admin password using database because `user/reset` page on the UI gives me below error

```
Server Error
An internal server error occurred
```

I prefer to change it using accessing database

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change passwords using paster

Activate your virtualenv (if any) and run:

```
paster --plugin=ckan user setpass USERNAME -c YOUR_CONFIG_FILE
```

You will be prompted to enter a new password